# Pagination in wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

This may be an easy but I cannot get it figured out. I have searched for hours with no luck on my situation. I need to get pagination to work with my_query

```
    <?php   
    $count = 0;
    $id_suffix = 1;
    $items_per_row = 4;
    $quality = 90;      
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;             
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'post_type' => 'portfolio') );
    $grid_class = 'grid_3';
    $desired_width = 220;
    $desired_height = 190;
    $terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_categories' ); 
    $count_terms = count( $terms ); 
?>

//some php code 

<?php while ( $wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post(); //query the "portfolio" custom post type for portfolio items ?>


//some more php code 


<?php endwhile;?>
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'thematic')) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'thematic')) ?></div>
</ul>
```

I got the pagination to display but when clicking on another page it shows the same portfolio items. Any help would be appreciated.

I got the pagination to show using wp-pagenavi but the same issue with not changing the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @maiorano84 and @s_ha_dum for pointing me in the right direction. I wanted to update this post for anybody that runs into the problem. The problem I was having was making the pagination work on the a static front page. After reading in the codex I figured out my problem.

Instead of `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` 
I had to use 
`$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`

That one little mistake is what kept the pagination to work. so the final code looked like this.

```
<?php   
    $count = 0;
    $id_suffix = 1;
    $items_per_row = 4;
    $quality = 90;
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'paged' => $paged
    ) );
    $grid_class = 'grid_3';
    $desired_width = 220;
    $desired_height = 190;
    $terms = get_terms( 'portfolio_categories' ); 
    $count_terms = count( $terms ); 
?>
```

//Some php code

```
<?php while ( $my_query -> have_posts()) : $my_query -> the_post(); //query the "portfolio" custom post type for portfolio items ?>


  (Some more php code)

<?php endwhile;
wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $my_query ) );    ?>
</ul><!-- END .portfolio-gallery -->
```

?>

Answer (score 6):

You are constructing the `$paged` variable but aren't using it.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;             
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
  'posts_per_page' => '4', 
  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
  'paged' => $paged // this is the missing part
) );
```

WordPress uses the `$wp_query` variable name. You should probably use a different one.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to suggest using the offset parameter, but your way is better. Also, yes, changing the instance name from $wp_query to something else is essential.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am having the same issue(pagination not changing portfolio items).

Comment: btw I changed `$wp_query` to `$my_query` and now the pagination is gone completely.

Comment: Any additional help would be greatly appreciated. I am stuck with the pages showing below the portfolio but when clicked it just shows the original 4 items, no matter which page is clicked.